# Sandbox in iphone destroyed after jailbroken?

Tags: ios, iphone, sandbox

So this is my current situation. I am using a iOS5.1 jailbroken phone (redsn0w) and I have written an application which is stored in `/var/mobile/Applications` which enumerates the iPhone file paths and list files that are readable  using `isReadableAtFilePath`. By right, the sandbox feature in iPhone would prevent my app from reading other apps so my application would not output any file paths that are in /var/mobile/Applications (except for its own). However, the weird thing is that my output consists of file paths that are from other apps.

Why is this happening. I thought that the sandbox feature allows apps to read and write files from only its own "sandbox" directory? How is my method of `isReadableAtFilePath` being able to retrieve paths outside of its own "sandbox" directory? Does jailbreaking your phone gives apps in the "sandbox" directory full access the the iphone system?

Answer (score 0):

If your a developer and you jailbreak, it will seriously mess with your ios device:

for example, you can't make test in-app purchases, or, you'll get full access in sandbox mode (like whats happening to you right now) I recommend `un-jailbreaking` your device, as it will make better for testing, or, alternatively, you could use another device for testing.

Either way, you `shouldn't test your applications on a jailbroken device`, as you won't get either what regular users get, or what regular jailbroken users will see.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe different jailbreaking software have different effect on the sandbox

Comment: @user2541163 Different software shouldn't have any effect on the things I talked about.